# Рекурсивный спуск

Tags: c++

Нужно было решить задачу методом динамического программирования(решение ниже). Кто-нибудь может рассказать о рекурсивном спуске? Где, что почитать. Потому что все, что я имею сейчас, это небольшой пример ниже.(Так как эту задачу теперь необходимо решить рекурсивным спуском)

**UPD: добавил решение с использованием рекурсии, но не уверен, что это можно назвать рекурсивным спуском**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Решение методом динамического программирования:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


double minPoly( const string &S, double x )
{
   int LEN = S.size();

   vector< vector< vector<double> > > P( LEN, vector< vector<double> >( LEN, vector<double>( LEN, 0.0 ) ) );

   for ( int i = 0; i < LEN; i++ ) P[i][i][0] = S[i] - '0';                   

   for ( int run = 2; run <= LEN; run++ )                                   
   {                                                 
      for ( int i = 0, j = i + run - 1; i <= LEN - run; i++, j++ )          
      {
         P[i][j][0] = 10 * P[i][j-1][0] + P[j][j][0];                         
         for ( int deg = 1; deg < run; deg++ )                             
         {
            P[i][j][deg] = P[i][i][0] + x * P[i+1][j][deg-1];                 
            for ( int c = i + 1; c < j - deg + 1; c++ ) P[i][j][deg] = min( P[i][j][deg], P[i][c][0] + x * P[c+1][j][deg-1] );
         }
      }
   }

   return *min_element( P[0][LEN-1].begin(), P[0][LEN-1].begin()+LEN );       
}


int main()
{
   string S;
   double x;
   cout << "Input S: ";   cin >> S;
   cout << "Input x: ";   cin >> x;
   cout << "Minimum polynomial is " << minPoly( S, x ) << '\n';
}
```

**С использованием рекурсии:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


double minPoly( const string &S, int i, double P1, double P2, double x, double xpower )
{
   if ( i == S.size() ) return P1 + P2;
   int digit = S[i] - '0';
   double left  = minPoly( S, i + 1, P1     , 10 * P2 + xpower * digit, x, xpower     );
   double right = minPoly( S, i + 1, P1 + P2,   ( xpower * x ) * digit, x, xpower * x );
   return min( left, right );
}


double minPoly( const string &S, double x )
{
   return minPoly( S, 1, 0, S[0] - '0', x, 1 );
}


int main()
{
   string S;
   double x;
   cout << "Input S: ";   cin >> S;
   cout << "Input x: ";   cin >> x;
   cout << "Minimum polynomial is " << minPoly( S, x ) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: А не проще ли было бы записать и конвертировать в double числа из S в вектор a и сортировать по возрастанию, если x<1 и по убыванию, если x>=1, затем считать выражение?

Comment: @KseniyaSinickaya Возможно

Comment: Я очень сомневаюсь, что вам для решения этой задачи нужно применять метод рекурсивного спуска для синтаксического анализа, про который написано в вики по этому запросу, поэтому я предполагаю, что в вашем случае под ним понимается просто рекурсия. Обычно в математике "какой-то" спуск - это метод решения задачи через решение меньших, более простых. Нередко при доказательстве от противного в олимпиадных задачах используется метод бесконечного спуска (кстати, существует доказательство иррациональности sqrt(2) с его помощью).

Comment: И мне кажется, что в вашем случае под рекурсивным спуском понимается просто любое адекватное решение, использующее рекурсию. Но вообще, если у вас вопросы по формулировке задания, наверное, вам стоит задавать тому, кто вам его выдал. Ну и о вашем решении через рекурсию - в моем понимании у вас вполне себе рекурсивный спуск, но я подозреваю, что там O(2^n) получилось. Вы запускали второй алгоритм на строках длиннее 30 символов? Не зависало? Просто мне кажется, что существует вполне квадратное решение (а мб и жадник работает), которое можно легко как в виде дп, так и в виде рекурсии написать.

Comment: @EzikBro Да, действительно очень долго считает